# WebStorm and TypeScript is not finding dependency injections in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webstorm

An AngularJS component in TypeScript:

```
class MyComponentCtrl {
    static $inject = ['MyService'];
    constructor(private MyService) {
      MyService.testfn(55); // No error in typescript
    }
}

class MyComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    constructor() {
        this.controller = MyComponentCtrl;
        this.template = 'hello';
    }
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .component('MyComponent', new MyComponent());
```

An AngularJS service in TypeScript:

```
class MyService {
    constructor() {

    }

    public testfn(age: number) {
        console.log(age);
    }
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .service('MyService', MyService);
```

When I hit <kbd>Cmd + Click</kbd> on the `testfn` in WebStorm, it's not found ("No decleration to go to"). Also, the TypeScript compiler is not giving error when I use `testfn` with invalid argument.

When I click on `MyService` in `static $inject` WebStorm finds it correctly.

Can I structure this differently somehow so WebStorm and TypeScript finds it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injected `MyService` is `any`, so it doesn't cause type error.

It's impossible for IDE or TypeScript to determine that it is an instance of `MyService` service. Also, injecting it as `MyService` is misleading, because it's class instance, not a class itself.

A class should be exported:

```
export class MyService {...}
```

It should be imported and specified as injected service type:

```
class MyComponentCtrl {
    static $inject = ['MyService'];
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
      myService.testfn(55);
    }
}
```